# `complete` attribute for iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

It seems that `<iframe>` does not have a `complete` attribute like `<img>` does.  Because of this, it seems like iframes cannot dependably work with `onload`.  For `<img>`, I can do:

```
$("img").on("load", loadFunc).each(function () {
    if (this.complete) {
        this.trigger("load");
    }
});
```

However if you replace `<img>` with `<iframe>` this does not work consistently.  There is no indication anywhere that `<iframe>` has a `complete` attribute, so I wouldn't expect this to work.

Is there any way to dependably determine when an iframe has loaded or otherwise trigger an event when the iframe's content is available?

Comment: Have you seen cases where the onload event was triggered but the iframe content was not available? Now I am getting worried...

Comment: @Christophe I think it has to do with the fact that the iframe is loading content from a script.  I need to be able to tell when the script inside of the iframe loads actually

Comment: And this is not taken care of in the iframe load event? (I assume you are not talking about an async ajax call, which would be a completely different scenario)

Comment: @Christophe it's not an ajax call actually, just a script tag.  This discussion probably belongs in a separate question, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('#iframeid').ready(function () {
    //On Load Complete Code.
});
```

Edit:

Didn't notice you want the iframe tag itself, instead of an id. But it seems to work anyways.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/tFhhH/

Comment: Nice answer never the less :D +1!

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, $().ready can fire earlier than the onload event.

Answer (score 0):

An idea could be to handle the load event of the iframe and set a variable to true and the event is called. Then you just need to check that variable to see if the iframe is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#iframeid").load(function (){
// At this point the iframe window is fully loaded
// no need to check for an additional "complete" state
});
```

`$().ready` on the other hand will tell you when the DOM is fully loaded. This can happen before the onload event.

Comment: right, this part of your question is correct. The problem is that you try to add something more, while it is not necessary.